# Datatables - is that possible to reload/redraw table without destroy filters?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like to know is that possible to reload table data without destroy filters or reset ordering.

Comment: http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2012/05/28/how-to-refresh-a-datatable-without-losing-your-current-page-or-ordering/

Comment: What version of the jQuery DataTables are you using? Also post your initialization code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `table.draw("full-hold")` or `table.draw(false)`, it will redraw the table without resetting search, ordering and paging

Check the documentation of `draw` : https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()